# UIBlurEffect in UIVisualEffectView & Performance

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uivisualeffectview, uiblureffect

Hope someone with extensive knowledge in drawing performance in **UIBlurEffect** with **UIVisualEffectView** can give me tips to extract best performance....

---

### What I got

So I have several **UIVisualEffectView's** with **UIBlurEffect**

```
var blurView1 = UIVisualEffectView()
blurView1 = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .light))
self.view.addSubview(blurView1)

var blurView2 = UIVisualEffectView()
blurView2 = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .light))
self.view.addSubview(blurView2)
```

---

### Issue

When I have several (>5) of these **UIVisualEffectView's**, I notice a significant drop in frames in graphics performance.

---

### What I tried So far

I tried creating one common **UIBlurEffect** and reusing it for every **UIVisualEffectView**:

```
let commonBlurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)

var blurView1 = UIVisualEffectView()
blurView1 = UIVisualEffectView(effect: commonBlurEffect)
self.view.addSubview(blurView1)

var blurView2 = UIVisualEffectView()
blurView2 = UIVisualEffectView(effect: commonBlurEffect)
self.view.addSubview(blurView2)
```

With above, I notice a slight improvement (may be not?), but still not acceptable.

---

### Question

What are tricks and tips I can use to extract maximum performance out of **UIVisualEffectView**'s with **UIBlurEffect**?

Comment: Been noticing the same! Even though I only have a single view, it's lagging pretty hard. To be fair tho, it's overlaying a video stream from the camera

Answer (score 0):

UIBlurEffect is costly. It adds multiple render passes and should be used carefully when performance is critical (scrolling complex collections, animations, playing video etc). Apple recommends limiting blurred areas, and use darker effect style. Also keep an eye on the number of redraws for areas covered by blur effect views. Static is the best.

Multiple blur effect views sounds like an overkill to me. Consider compositing their contents into single UIVisualEffectView (adding to its contentView) and maybe masking contentView then (if needed).

Refer to related WWDC archive https://docs.huihoo.com/apple/wwdc/2014/419_advanced_graphics_and_animation_performance.pdf for details.